# CiviCase Use Examples for Donor/Grant

Tags: civicase, evaluating-civicrm

I was wondering if anyone would mind sharing some screen shots of your setup of CiviCase to track donor and/or grant interactions. The only samples I can seem to find are affiliated with more traditional case management. I have been reading a lot of different threads but I feel like I am missing a piece of the puzzle, and cannot seem to find a guide specific to these areas for setup. And image should help, unless you know where a guide specific to this can be found. Thanks!

Comment: Mary - it might be more helpful if you can spell out the steps you want in the workflow/process. This screenshot may help but we find everyone's use case is a bit different http://i.imgur.com/Iq3xT99.png

Comment: @petednz-fuzion - That looks like an answer to me, if you make it one I'll upvote it!

Comment: I apologize, I have been swamped lately. What I would like to figure out is how to properly setup civicase to track donor contacts for past, present, and future. For example, I help lead a tour today for a potential sponsor and want to add this note. I also want to set a reminder for a follow up e-mail and phone call.

Answer (score 1):

This [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCznr.png) shows one variation but of course everyone's use case is a bit different

Answer (score 0):

I realized I was looking at this wrong, and that activities are the best way to accomplish what I wanted to track.